Webhook Listener in Power Platform
I'm working on a project in which I'm syncing the data between Microsoft Dataverse(via Model Driven App) and MyWebsite. To sync data from 'MS Dataverse' to 'Mywebsite', I'm using Cloud Flow(to call external API) and that seems working fine.
Now, in order to sync data from 'Mywebsite' to 'MS Dataverse' I'm unable to find any solution. Mywebsite has capability to set Webhook and trigger request whenever something is updated in 'Mywebsite', But, I'm not sure how to consume that request in 'MS Dataverse'(via Power Apps or Dynamics or Power Automate, etc).
Question - How to update Dataverse Table record whenever same record is updated in my Website?
I tried exploring the options in Power Automate and JavaScript Web-resource, but nothing worked.

Personally I suggest Power Automate if the workload is not too much, if you need to transfer big amount of data there are other options (like Azure Service Bus and queues)
Back to your question: to receive requests you can create a Power Automate flow with the trigger "When an HTTP request is received", as far as I know it can be only POST.
Note: to send data from Dataverse to external sources, you can also use webhooks:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/use-webhooks
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/register-web-hook
